# there's no more you?

Tags: american-english, dialects

I'm reading the lyrics of the song *So Sick*, and I'm puzzled about the following line:

> Gotta fix that calendar I have that's marked July 15th because since there's no more you. There's no more anniversary.

I understand "since" as meaning since July 15th, but "there's no more you" puzzles me for two reasons. First, why is the tense the present simple and not the present perfect, i.e. there has been no more you? Second, is it odd to say "no more you" although we can say "no more milk"? Would it be more natural to say "there has been no more of you"?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you sure "because since" is equal to "because"? A more likely analysis is to treat "since" as an adverbial, as in "I haven't seen him ever since."

Comment: You understand wrong.  It's "... because, since there's no more you, there's no more anniversary."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because song lyrics are off-topic because they often do not reflect "proper" English.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem comes from assuming "since July 15th"  That's not what the song is saying.
As Rudy M pointed out the line is "no more'you'"

So what the song is trying to say is:
Because we are no longer in a relationship, i have to change my calendar.  I have July 15th marked int he future as our anniversary, but now that we are broken up it is no longer an important day.

Comment: Since when is "because since" equal to "because" alone? That'd appear to be a usage unattested elsewhere.

Comment: I question the OP's punctuation. It makes more sense if we read the quote as "... since there's no more you, there's no more anniversary". That whole phrase then forms the reason that follows the word "because".

Comment: The sentences "Since i have a job I get a paycheck"  and "Because I have a job I get a paycheck"  are identical in meaning

Comment: I agree with Lawrence: *Because there's no more anniversary* is why the calendar has to be fixed, and *since there's no more you* is why there's no more anniversary. Compare *I'm solvent because since I have a job I get a paycheck.*

Comment: As Lawrence suggests, the "punctuation" of the original is the musical phrasing, not normal English punctuation.  (This is one reason why lyrics are generally off-topic.)

Answer (score -1):

Being that it's a music lyric, I wouldn't really consider too much. It sucks, but sometimes the language is sacrificed for the sake of a rhyme, or to make a good flow with melody. I am bothered with the redundancy because since, pick one. I wouldn't use both in a line.

As for your question of why it's not `there **has** been no more you`, I think it can work, but the way it is now works too, as would `there will be no more you`.

And second, whether it's odd to say `no more you`, I think the song really means `there's no more 'you'`, as referring to the individual to whom the lyric is directed.

Comment: *Because (since there's no more you) there's no more anniversary.* The capital on *There* marks the beginning of a new line.